# Javascript (howler js) How to pass child property to parent?

Tags: javascript, howler.js

Good day everyone, I'm fairly new to Javascript so please forgive me if this is a stupid question. I've been trying to google this, some say to use super() but I'm getting an error of undefined.

I'm using howlerJS. My goal is not to rewrite the same 'onend' listener/function whenever I instantiate a new Howl.

```
class ChildHowl extends Howl{
    ...how can i insert 'onend' prop here?...
}
```

```
var myHowl = new ChildHowl({
  src: ['audio.wav'],
  // how to move this onend to ChildHowl as a default
  onend: function() {
        console.log('audio ended');
        .... some stuff ....
      }
});
```

Thank you everyone in advance. You're understanding and consideration is highly appreciated.

Update: Fixed thank you Fabien Auréjac for the help!

```
class ChildHowl extends Howl{ 
  constructor(obj) { 
    let onend=function() { 
      console.log('audio ended'); 
    }; 
    super({ src:obj.src, onend:onend }); 
  } 
}

var myHowl = new ChildHowl({
  src: ['audio.wav']
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, you can pass the argument via super(); in order to get the constructor of your parent class to receive it.

```
class Howl {
    constructor(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        this.src = obj.src;
        this.onend = obj.onend;
    }
}
class ChildHowl extends Howl{
    constructor(obj) {
        super(obj);
        this.onend();
    }
}
var myHowl = new ChildHowl({
    src: ['audio.wav'],
    onend: function() {
        console.log('audio ended');
    }
});
```

Comment: That's the right idea, but you probably don't want to trigger `onend` in the constructor (unless it's for demonstration purposes only to show that `this.onend` is what you expect it to be).

Comment: Exactly, I should have meant it was only for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much @FabienAuréjac for the answer. I actually want to remove the "onend" when I'm initializing or creating a new object and instead place it inside ChildHowl as a default. Let me know if this is something doable?

Comment: Yes, for sure, but since you use a library that affects onend itself, and manage it itself the only thing you have to do is to pass it via your child constructor.
here is an excerpt from Howler.js :
// Setup event listeners.
      self._onend = o.onend ? [{fn: o.onend}] : [];
The only thing you have to do is to pass it like I showed to you.
for example :
class ChildHowl extends Howl{
 constructor(obj) {
  let onend=function() {
   console.log('audio ended');
  };
  super({ src:obj.src, onend:onend });
 }
}

Comment: @FabienAuréjac it works! Thank you so much for your help.